# Python - move all files from one folder to another if their file names contain specified words

Tags: python, directory, file-move

I have a folder with many files named like `homeXXX_roomXXX_high.csv` or `homeXXX_roomXXX_low.csv`, where the `XXX` part is replaced with a three-digit number.

I want to use some code to move the files into separate folders based on the number next to "home" in the filename. For example, I want to specify that files with names starting `home101`, `home103`, `home320`, `home553`, etc. should all be moved into folder A whereas those starting with `home555`, `home431`, `home105` should go to FolderB.

I have this code so far:

```
import shutil
import os

source = '/path/to/source_folder'
dest1 = '/path/to/FolderA'
dest2 = '/path/to/FolderB'

files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    if (f.startswith("home101") or f.startswith("home103")):
        shutil.move(f, dest1)
    elif (f.startswith("home431") or f.startswith("home555")):
        shutil.move(f, dest2)
```

However, it's tedious to specify all the `if` and `else` cases. I'd like to use some kind of structured data, such as a `list`, to specify groups of "home" numbers and the corresponding folder paths. How can I do this in Python?

Comment: "Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks." Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is **not a discussion forum**. I have many ideas, all the time, but none of them are relevant to the problem here. But more importantly, that is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). We also are [not interested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950) in "thanks". I will try to edit the question to show proper style, but I am not sure I understand what you hope to accomplish.

Comment: Okay, after reading it a few times in order to finish the editing, it seems clear enough; but there are many ways to do this, and it will involve multiple steps regardless. In general, we don't try to teach *design* here, only individual concepts. You may find an actual discussion forum, such as Reddit or Quora, more useful for the kind of help you are seeking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you can use another for, it would look something like this:

```
import shutil
import os

source = '/path/to/source_folder'
dest1 = '/path/to/FolderA'
dest2 = '/path/to/FolderB'

list1 = ["home101", "home103"]
list2 = ["home431", "home555"]

files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    for home1 in list1:
        if f.startswith(home1):
            shutil.move(f, dest1)
            break

    for home2 in list2:
        if f.startswith(home2):
            shutil.move(f, dest2)
            break
```

You can also create a function:

```
def check_and_move(file, list_of_patterns, destination):
    for pattern in list_of_patterns:
        if file.startswith(pattern):
            shutil.move(file, destination)
```

and the code will get cleaner because you avoid repetition :)

```
for f in files:
    check_and_move(f, list1, dest1)
    check_and_move(f, list2, dest2)
    # etc...
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. It was easy to add more lists and folders to the code.

Comment: I've edited with an update, wanted to do it even better :) if you have any problems implementing just tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array for folderA that contains the "home+number"

```
FolderAGroup = ['home101', 'home103', 'homeXXX', 'homeXXX']
```

And if they get split like you say with a "_" use this code to filter them
Won't work if they are not split like that.

```
files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
  parts = f.split('_')
  # Get the first part of the filename before the _
  home_number = parts[0]
  # Check if the home number is in the FolderA group array
  if home_number in FolderAGroup:
    shutil.move(f, dest1)
  else:
    shutil.move(f, dest2)
```

You can expand with more elif statements if you would want more folders.

Answer (score 0):

If the names `homexxx` are incremental, you could try something like this:

```
home_names_list_1 = []
home_names_list_2 = []
for i in range(100):
    home_names_list_1.append("home" + str(i))

for i in range(100,200):
    home_names_list_2.append("home" + str(i))

for file in files:
    moved = False
    for name in home_names_list_1:
        if file.startswith(name):
            print("move somewhere")
            moved = True
            break
    if moved:
        break
    
    for name in home_names_list_2:
        if file.startswith(name):
            print("move somewhere else")
            break
    
    print(" did not move because did not match anything")
```